# Download a file from a link was sent to an email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I am trying to send an email with download link to a file but on click on the file nothing happen i can not download the file from the link.

After i click on the link to download file it is open empty tab in the browser but file not downloaded yet

```
public ActionResult DownLoadTraining(ContactUsModel model)
    {
        SendEmail sendemail = new SendEmail();

        string toEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactUsEmail"];

        var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "Firstname", model.Firstname },
            { "Lastname", model.Lastname },
            { "Email", model.Email },
            { "Orgnization", model.Orgnization },
            { "Message", model.Message }
        };
//here i build the link to donwload it .
        string DownLoadlink = "<a download  href='http://www.yoursite.com/folders/yourfile.txt' target='_blank'>Click me to DownLoad</a>";


        if (keys != null && keys.Count != 0)
        {
            string body = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, keys.Select(x => $"{x.Key}: {x.Value}"));

            sendemail.Send(new EmailModel()
            {
                Body = DownLoadlink,
                Subject = "DownLoad Training Message",
                To = new List<string>() { model.Email },

            });

            return Json(new { val = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { val = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Any advice .

Comment: Most browsers only allow downloads from the same domain as the HTML was served from. Since people see the email on GMail/Yahoo/whatever, it won't work.

Comment: Where exactly are you redirecting your user with this url?

Answer (score 0):

Create one method to download file when user click URL from email.
Generate link as

> http://yourdomain.com/Controller/Action?FilePath=/Folder/FileName.txt

```
public FileResult Download(string FilePath)
{
    DocPath = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(FilePath);

    var comPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(FilePath);
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(comPath);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(comPath);
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```